# Running Sum by Date criteria in a query (Duplicate Dates)

Tags: ms-access

I want to obtain a running sum in query. I'm using the following running sum formula

```
RunningSum: CCur(Nz(DSum("[Debit]","[Debit]","[CustomerID] =" & [CustomerID] & " AND [vDate] < " & [vDate] & "")))
```

But it is not working. My purpose is to obtain sum of `Debit` for all smaller than the current date field, something like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qoO7.jpg

After going through different threads, I could not find any solution for my problem. I don't know that how I can get the sum of older debit amounts if there is duplicate date.

Comment: Do you not have a unique ID?

Comment: Yes i have a unique field ID which is autonumber.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to use the id rather than the date, because you have duplicate dates, unfortunately, you cannot rely on an autonumber to always increase by date. The alternatives would be to add a time element to date, though this may be more trouble than it is worth, or a sequence number when the date is duplicated.

Comment: I can do this though the report with sorting by date, and then running sum of the debit field. But i want this running sum for more other calculations. In report i have to add new unbound text boxes to complete my task. But these text boxes can not be summed up in footer for grand totals. If i could be able to get the running sum though query method, i could easily add more calculations in query and then easily report can be created with grand totals in footer.

Comment: It is much easier with a report. For the grand totals, you can just sum debit. If you group by customer, you can have running sum over group, sum of debit for the group in the group footer and grand total for all customers in the report footer.

Comment: But i want to do more calculation though running sum, for the purpose i have to add more fields, say =sum([text12]+[RunningSum]) in the footer. Report gives error and says to enter the parameter value for Text12.

Comment: You cannot add calculated fields in a report. I do not know what text12 is, but you might be able to say `Sum([Debit]+[Text12])` or `[Text12]+Sum([Debit])`. The problem with a query is that you will get the same sum for every matched date (50,000 for 2-7-12 in your example).

Comment: I m really stuck with this problem. Is there any other method though i can accomplish my task

Comment: I do not have a clear picture of your problem. Can you put a version of your database on dropbox?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3a859yemqpsibz/sampleDB.accdb here is the link of drop box.There are two reports one "Report Based on Query" in which i get running sum though ID field (IDtrasn) which is autonumber. Second Report is "Running Sum though report" in which i have sorted the fields by vDate and then calculated running, which i want. Then i have made some other calculations. This report is working very fine as i want but problem is again, i can not calculate the running totals at the end of the report as many of fields are calculated fields. It asks for those fields upon opening report.

Comment: I reckon you need a combination of the two reports. a little bit of the query, a little bit of report with running sum. I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing will be to just refer to running sums for all the controls you want to add. For example "31 to 60 Days" is text29 on your report. Create a hidden control called, say, R31to60 and set to Running sum over group, then in the footer, put a text box and set the control source to:

```
=[R31to60]
```

It will show the last value for the running sum, that is, the total.

In design view, the highlight shows the running sum control and total. The control can be shrunk down and hidden.

[image: Running sum design]

In report view you can see the "total" field shows the last value for running sum.

[image: running sum report]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked fine. And i don't need any query now. I can do it simply by report as you suggested. I have been searching for it for last two months.